# NSTableView overlapping rows when scrolling

Tags: scroll, nstableview, appkit

I'm having an overlapping row problem when scrolling in table. The data gets displayed properly, but when I scroll down the text in the rows are overlapping with text from other rows.

Here is the code to create the `NStableView`:

```
-(void)addTableAt:(NSRect)rect withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withIndex:(int) index
{
    // Get the table
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"table_0"]) {
        // The view
        view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, rect.size.width,rect.size.height)];
    }

    // The ScrollView for the table
    NSScrollView *tableScrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(index*rect.size.width, 0.0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];

    // The table view
    NSTableView *tableView = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(index*rect.size.width, 0.0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];
    [tableView setIdentifier:identifier];
    [tableView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];
    [tableView setHeaderView:nil];

    // Set up the right click menu
    NSMenu *theMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contextual Menu"];
    NSString *menuString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d", @"table", index];
    NSMenuItem *menuItem = [theMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Submit to Restore" action:@selector(fileRestore:) keyEquivalent:menuString atIndex:0];
    [menuItem setEnabled:YES];
    [menuItem setTarget:self];
    [tableView setMenu:theMenu];

    // Set the column
    NSTableColumn *column =[[NSTableColumn alloc]initWithIdentifier:identifier];
    [column.headerCell setTitle:@"Header Title"];
    [column setWidth:245];

    // Add the column tot he table
    [tableView addTableColumn:column];

    // Set the source and the delegate
    [tableView setDataSource:self];
    [tableView setDelegate:self];
    [tableView setAllowsMultipleSelection: YES];

    // Add the table to the scroll view
    [tableScrollView setDocumentView:tableView];

    // Create the view and the table scroll view
    [view setFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, (index+1)*rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];
    [view addSubview:tableScrollView];

    // Set the view into the main scroll view
    [main_scrollview setDocumentView:view];

    // Add the main  scroll view to the main view
    [main_view addSubview:main_scrollview];
    [main_view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Do NOT try and create an NSTableView programmatically.

Use Interface Builder and use the built in table view enclosed in a scroll view.
Interface Builder -> Tools -> Library -> Objects "NSTableView in an NSScrollView"

There are too many things that need to be hooked up in the correct order.

It looks like you need to add multiple tables in your app?
If that's the case, you can create multiple instances by reusing a nib multiple times.

Here's stripped down example code for a controller class which I use as a template
to instantiate multiple instances of a nib.
(Details like window/view management is left out... this is just a skeleton template)

In this case CHelpText is my controller, and my nib is named CHelpText.xib

```
@interface CHelpText : NSWindowController {
   IBOutlet NSTextView *mTextView;
   IBOutlet NSView *mTransparentView;
   NSArray              *mTopLevelObjects;
}
@property(retain) NSArray              *mTopLevelObjects;

+(void)showHelp:(NSString *)iHelpText
          title:(NSString *)iHelpTitle;
-(void)awakeFromNib;
- (IBAction) closeWindow: (id)sender
@end


@implementation CHelpText
@synthesize mTopLevelObjects;
+(void)showHelp:(NSString *)iHelpText
          title:(NSString *)iHelpTitle
{
   ////////////// BUILD CHelpText ///////////////////////////////// 
   NSBundle *theClassBundle;   
   theClassBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; 
   NSNib *theNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"CHelpText" bundle:theClassBundle];
   CHelpText *theController = [CHelpText alloc];

   NSArray *theTopLevelObjects;   
   [theNib instantiateNibWithOwner:theController  
                   topLevelObjects:&theTopLevelObjects]; 
   theController.mTopLevelObjects = theTopLevelObjects;
   [theNib autorelease];
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    if ([[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(awakeFromNib)])
        [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (IBAction) closeWindow: (id)sender
{
   [[self window] performClose:self];
   self.mTopLevelObjects = nil;
   [self autorelease];
}
```